# Table in HTML-CSS

Tags: html, css

[image] Hello guys . I have a problem. As we see the characteristic of a table, when hovering over each cell, the background color of that cell turns yellow. I want the background color of the entire row to turn yellow when hovering over each cell.

For example, when you hover over Amazon, 4162 and 5327 and 00:24:34 and their background color becomes yellow.

```
//////////// My Html code ///////////

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"  />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Index2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Sites</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Avrage</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="Google">Google</td>
            <td class="Value">9518</td>
            <td class="Value">6369</td>
            <td class="Value">1:32:50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Twitter">Twitter</td>
                <td class="Value">7326</td>
                <td class="Value">10437</td>
                <td class="Value">00:51:22</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Amazon">Amazon</td>
                <td class="Value">4162</td>
                <td class="Value">5327</td>
                <td class="Value">00:24:34</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                    <td class="Linkedin">Linkedin</td>
                    <td class="Value">3654</td>
                    <td class="Value">2961</td>
                    <td class="Value">00:12:10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="TopLearn">TopLearn</td>
                <td class="Value">2002</td>
                <td class="Value">4135</td>
                <td class="Value">00:46:19</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="GitHub">GitHub</td>
                    <td class="Value">4623</td>
                    <td class="Value">3486</td>
                    <td class="Value">00:31:52</td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
////////////My Css code////////////

body
{
    background-color: rgb(30, 33, 50);
}
div{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
table{
    margin-top: 4vw;
    
}
th{
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size :20px;
    color: rgb(108, 186, 224);
}
th,td
{
     padding: 1.25vw 12.5vw 1.25vw 1.25vw;  
    /* padding: 20px 200px 20px 20px;  */
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
background-color: rgb(45, 50, 69);
}
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
background-color: rgb(38, 44, 60);
}
tr:nth-child(1)
{
background-color: rgb(30, 33, 50);
}
th,td{
    text-align: left;
}
/***************************************************************************************************/
td.Google{    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
    
    
}
td.Amazon{    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
    
    
}
td.Twitter{    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hover rule around the `tr` and then target each `td` therein. To exclude highlighting of the first cells in each row (GitHub, Amazon, etc.), you can use CSS negation to target `td`s which are *not* the first child of the highlighted row.

```css
tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(30, 33, 50);
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  margin-top: 4vw;
}

th {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(108, 186, 224);
}

th,
td {
  padding: 1.25vw 12.5vw 1.25vw 1.25vw;
  /* padding: 20px 200px 20px 20px;  */
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(45, 50, 69);
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(38, 44, 60);
}

tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: rgb(30, 33, 50);
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
}


/***************************************************************************************************/

td.Google {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
}

td.Amazon {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
}

td.Twitter {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(250, 83, 113);
}

tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Sites</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Avrage</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Google">Google</td>
        <td class="Value">9518</td>
        <td class="Value">6369</td>
        <td class="Value">1:32:50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Twitter">Twitter</td>
        <td class="Value">7326</td>
        <td class="Value">10437</td>
        <td class="Value">00:51:22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="Amazon">Amazon</td>
        <td class="Value">4162</td>
        <td class="Value">5327</td>
        <td class="Value">00:24:34</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="Linkedin">Linkedin</td>
        <td class="Value">3654</td>
        <td class="Value">2961</td>
        <td class="Value">00:12:10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TopLearn">TopLearn</td>
        <td class="Value">2002</td>
        <td class="Value">4135</td>
        <td class="Value">00:46:19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="GitHub">GitHub</td>
        <td class="Value">4623</td>
        <td class="Value">3486</td>
        <td class="Value">00:31:52</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the row will also be hovered over while the child is being hovered over, just give the row a hover style as well.

```css
td {
border: 1px solid gray;
}

td:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

tr:hover{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1.1</td>
<td>2.1</td>
<td>3.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.2</td>
<td>2.2</td>
<td>3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.3</td>
<td>2.3</td>
<td>3.3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```